# Financial functions in Embarcadero Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

does anyone know whats is equivalents in Delphi of C#/Excel **financial functions**: **PMT, IPMT** and **PPMT** ?

Answer (score 10):

Financial functions are in `System.Math` unit.

They have full name such as `NetPresentValue`.

The documentation is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Business_And_Finance_Routines).